# Read data from form, and creating object using it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a problem with **reading data from my HTML form, and then creating an object using that data**. I am making a simple front end portfolio website, and in "Contact" part I would like to manage users to contact me using this form. Here is the code, so if you have any suggestion, please let me know.

This is how I created HTML form and JS:

```js
var users = [];

var createUser = function(){
  var form = document.myForm;
  //getting data
  if(form.name.value == ""){
 alert("Please, enter your name.");
  }else{
 var name = form.name.value;
  }
  if(form.surname.value == ""){
 alert("Please, enter your surname.");
  }else{
 var surname = form.surname.value;
  }
  if(form.email.value == ""){
 alert("Please, enter your email.");
  }else{
 var email = form.email.value;
  }
  if(form.phone.value == ""){
 alert("Please, enter your phone number.");
  }else{
 var phone = form.phone.value;
  }
    
  var radSex = form.radSex;
  var sex;
  for(var i=0; i<radSex.length; i++){
 if(radSex[i].checked){
   sex = radSex[i].value;
 }
  }
    
  var radAge = form.radAge;
  var age;
  for(var i=0; i<radAge.length; i++){
 if(radAge[i].checked){
   age = radAge[i].value;
 }
  } 
  var message = form.getElementByClassName("message").value;
  //creating user
  var user = {
 firstName: name,
 lastName: surname,
 email: email,
 phoneNumber: phone,
 sex: sex,
 age: age,
 message: message
  };
  //putting into array
  users.push(user);
    
    
};
function check(){
  alert(users[0]);
};
  //listening for event
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitButton");
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", createUser);
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", check);
```

```html
<form action="submit" name="myForm">
 <p>
      <input type="text" name="name" value="Name" class="textbox">
    </p>
 <p>
      <input type="text" name="surname" value="Surname" class="textbox">
    </p>
 <p>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="Email Address" class="textbox">    
    </p>
 <p>
      <input type="text" name="phone" value="Phone Number" class="textbox">
    </p>

 <p>Sex:</p>
 <p> 
      <label>Male&nbsp;</label>
   <input type="radio" name="radSex" value="male" checked="checked">
      <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Female&nbsp;</label>
   <input type="radio" name="radSex" value="female">       
 </p>

 <p>Age:</p>
   <p>
  <label>&lt;25&nbsp;</label> 
  <input type="radio" name="radAge" value="&lt;25" checked="checked">
        <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;25&lt;50&nbsp;</label> 
  <input type="radio" name="radAge" value="25&lt;50">
        <label>&nbsp;50&lt;100</label> 
  <input type="radio" name="radAge" value="50&lt;100">
   </p>
       
   <p>
        <textarea class="message">Message</textarea>
      </p>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="submitButton">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, you should use [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

```
$("form").serialize();
```

You can select one or more form elements.

Let say, you've large form with lots of fields in it, you can just use the `serialize` to collect (inputs with name only) all the field values by a single line.

```
$(function () {
   $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'post.php',
          data: $('form').serialize(),
          success: function () {
            alert('form was submitted');
          }
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you on your advice! It seems much more reasonable to do it like this. It helped me a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let submitButton = document.querySelector("#submitButton");

submitButton.addEventListener("click",function(){
  
  let nameValue = document.querySelector("[name=name]").value;
  let surnameValue = document.querySelector("[name=surname]").value;
  let emailValue = document.querySelector("[name=email]").value;
  let phoneValue = document.querySelector("[name=phone]").value;
  let sexValue = document.querySelector("[name=radSex]").value;
  let ageValue = document.querySelector("[name=radAge]").value;
  let messageValue = document.querySelector(".message").value;
  
  let backObject = {
    "name": nameValue,
    "surname": surnameValue,
    "email": emailValue,
    "phone": phoneValue,
    "sex": sexValue,
    "age": ageValue,
    "message": messageValue
  };
  
  console.log(backObject);
  
});
```

```html
<form action="submit" name="myForm">
 <p>
      <input type="text" name="name" value="Name" class="textbox">
    </p>
 <p>
      <input type="text" name="surname" value="Surname" class="textbox">
    </p>
 <p>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="Email Address" class="textbox">    
    </p>
 <p>
      <input type="text" name="phone" value="Phone Number" class="textbox">
    </p>

 <p>Sex:</p>
 <p> 
      <label>Male&nbsp;</label>
   <input type="radio" name="radSex" value="male" checked="checked">
      <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Female&nbsp;</label>
   <input type="radio" name="radSex" value="female">       
 </p>

 <p>Age:</p>
   <p>
  <label>&lt;25&nbsp;</label> 
  <input type="radio" name="radAge" value="&lt;25" checked="checked">
        <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;25&lt;50&nbsp;</label> 
  <input type="radio" name="radAge" value="25&lt;50">
        <label>&nbsp;50&lt;100</label> 
  <input type="radio" name="radAge" value="50&lt;100">
   </p>
       
   <p>
        <textarea class="message">Message</textarea>
      </p>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="submitButton">Send</button>
</form>
```